# How to calculate highscores from SQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Ok, I have two MYSQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `runTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `monstersKilled` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `profit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tasks` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `xpGain` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastupdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And,

```
CREATE TABLE  `users` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` text NOT NULL,
  `pass` text NOT NULL,
  `paypal` text NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `strikes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `session` text NOT NULL,
  `brand` text NOT NULL,
  `identifier` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=651 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see, sessions has a link to the user's ID. Now I want to make a total high scores PHP file, but with my little knowledge of php and little knowledge of MYSQL I wouldn't know how to start. The total high scores would be sorted by Total runtime.

Example:
In users I have user #1 (cody) & user #2 (Joe). Now, In sessions I have 3 sessions:

```
id, userID, runTime, monstersKilled, profit, tasks, xpGain, lastupdate
12, 1, 27, 14, 6200, 0, 5050, 1282325410
19, 1, 18, 1, 277, 1, 168, 1278897756
1968, 2, 195, 433, 111345, 4, 73606, 1280993244
```

The print out should be along the lines of:

```
Place, username, Total Run Time, Total Monsters Killed, Total profit, Total tasks, Total Exp Gain
1. Joe, 195, 433,11345,4,73606
2. Cody, 55, 15, 1, 5218
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT u.user,
         SUM(s.runtime) AS total_run_time,
         SUM(s.monsterskilled) AS total_monsters_killed,
         SUM(s.profit) AS total_profit,
         SUM(s.tasks) AS total_tasks, 
         SUM(s.xpgain) AS total_xp_gained
    FROM USERS u
    JOIN SESSION s ON s.userid = u.userid
GROUP BY u.user
ORDER BY total_run_time DESC
```

Comment: Good answer, I don't use MySQL much so don't know if it supports row ranges, but you would either want to have a SELECT TOP n or SELECT range as this query could easily get to be very slow with many users.

Comment: @Tom Gullen: MySQL's `LIMIT` syntax is equivalent to SQL Server's `TOP`, actually better than when you consider the `offset` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This script should output the highscores in a neat table for you.  Thanks to OMG Ponies for the SQL query.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';  // Database Host
$dbuser = 'user';       // Database User
$dbpass = 'password';   // Database Password
$dbname = 'database';   // Database Name

$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $db);

$limit = 10; // The number of users to show in the top highscores.  Set to 0 to show all

$sql = 'SELECT u.user,
         SUM(s.runtime) AS total_run_time,
         SUM(s.monsterskilled) AS total_monsters_killed,
         SUM(s.profit) AS total_profit,
         SUM(s.tasks) AS total_tasks, 
         SUM(s.xpgain) AS total_xp_gained
        FROM USERS u
        JOIN SESSION s ON s.userid = u.userid
        GROUP BY u.user
        ORDER BY total_run_time DESC';

if ($limit > 0) {
    $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$limit;
}

$get_scores = mysql_query($sql);
$scores = array();

$rank = 0;
while($score = mysql_fetch_array($get_scores)) {
    ++$rank;
    $scores[] = '<td>'.$rank.'</td><td>'.$score['user'].'</td><td>'.$score['total_run_time'].'</td><td>'.$score['total_monsters_killed'].'</td><td>'.$score['total_profit'].'</td><td>'.$score['total_tasks'].'</td><td>'.$score['total_xp_gained'].'</td>';
}

echo '<table><tbody>';
echo '<tr><td>Place</td><td>Username</td><td>Total Run Time</td><td>Total Monsters Killed, Total profit</td><td>Total tasks</td><td>Total Exp Gain</td></tr><tr>';
echo implode('</tr><tr>', $scores);
echo '</tr></tbody></table>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for simplifying my answer :).